# Move page number location on the first page of index to top right

Tags: memoir, page-numbering, fancyhdr, indexing, header

I am using `heading` page style for my thesis. As a requirement, the page numbers must be consistently at top-right for *all* pages.

My thesis has an index at the end. The page number on the first page of the index is at the bottom-center. But the other pages of the index are at top right. I am not able to make that one page (first page of the index) to be similar to the others. Here is an MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ucbthesis}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,columns=1,intoc=true]

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{headings}

\chapter{Introduction}
\index{One}
\lipsum

\chapter{Conclusion}
\index{Two}
\lipsum

\printindex

\newpage
This page has the correct page number on the top right.

\end{document}
```

I assume the first page of index uses the `plain` style. So, to fix the issue, I tried to modify the `plain` style with `fancyhdr` by:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

- First of all, I am not sure altering the plain style is a good idea. Is there a better solution? Can `makeindx` package be directly customized without calling `fancyhdr`?
- Second, the `fancyhdr` in the above changes the location of the page number of the index page from bottom-center to top-right, but the page number goes too far-right, out of the text margin. How do I make the page number of the index page to be *precisely* in the same location as the other pages?

---

**Edit:** apparently the setting with `\rhead{\thepage \hspace{2cm}}` produces the page number on the desired location.

Comment: Maybe you can share the MWE in general class (like `book`). Not in `ucbthesis `class

Comment: @Eddy, the `book` class does not have this issue on index pages. The `ucbthesis` is derived from `memoir`. Also, the `memoir` does not have this issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have `ucbthesis` class for my Latex